# Count lines that match specific regex pattern using python 3.x

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have a source UTF8 file (no BOM, windows EOL) that looks like this:

```
~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~
some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text

~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~
some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text
&&even_more_text_here

~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~
some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text

~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~
```

So there are 3 types of lines (4 if you count blank lines). My goal is to count each non-blank **type** using python regex. This is absolutely have to be regex-based solution using python 3.x, because I want to understand how it works.

My python script looks something like this:

```
import re, codecs
pattern = re.compile(r'some_expression_here')
count = 0
with codecs.open("some_input_file", "r", "UTF8") as inputFile:
    inputFile=inputFile.read()
    lines = re.findall(pattern, inputFile)
    for match in lines:
        count +=1
print (count)
```

The real problem I'm having is the actual regex expression.
`~.*~` seem to be able to match lines like 1, 4, 8 in my example above (if we count starting from 1)
`&&.*` matches line 6
But I can't figure out how to count non-marked lines, which are line 2,5,9.
In Notepad++ this expression `^(?!(~.*~)|(&&.*)).*` or simply this `^(?!~|&).*` works for me (even though it is not exactly correct), but all my attempts to replicate this in python failed...

**Edit**
`inputFile.read()` doesn't reads the file the way I expect it to (hello windows EOL). Which is may or may not be important. It's output looks like this:

```
~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~

some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text



~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~

some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text

&&even_more_text_here
```

Comment: I mean it matches lines 1, 4, 8 in my example if you start to count from 1. Not the internal logic or something.

Comment: Unless you add each time, lines 1, 4 and 8 are you non-marked lines.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean. I tested it and it matches exactly what I said it is. Count returns correct results, this is what matters.

Answer (score 1):

```
    x="~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~ \n   \n \nsome_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text \n"
    pattern=re.compile(r"(\S+)")
    print len(pattern.findall(x))
```

This gives count of all lines excluding space.So blank lines don't get counted.Hope this helps.

Comment: Nope. First of all this doesn't works in python 3.x at all. Secondly this doesn't deals with input FILE, correct handling EOLs and stuff. Third, with my actual example as input string the result is "8" lines while the correct answer is "3"

Comment: The result should be 8 rt.......all non blank lines........correct me if i m wrong...... and also for input File small changes are to be made.........which i guess can be incorporated straight away.......

Comment: The result should be THREE. Can you see the difference between searching for "each non-blank line" "and each non-blank TYPE" of the line. There are 3 types in total, we're searching for one of them!

Comment: You haven't explained what you want properly and that's why we are all having trouble with your question. The above does work in Python 3 - but the print statement doesn't, change that to print(len(pattern.findall(x))). You already worked out the file handling stuff. Explicit EOL handling is not required to handle this problem.

Comment: I know what to change it to. The fact is, it does not work "as is". I said multiple times I need a solution for python 3.x. Also I explained perfectly **"So there are 3 types of lines (4 if you count blank lines). My goal is to count each non-blank type using python regex."** which part of it you don't understand?

Comment: Non-blank means lines that are not empty. The other 3 types are all non-blank so that means that you want to count all of these. Your question was vague.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this pattern `^\w.*` with the re.MULTILINE flag`.

`re.UNICODE` flag should also be used for Python 2.

Here is a complete example:

```
import re, codecs

with codecs.open("input.txt", "r", "UTF8") as inputFile:
    data = inputFile.read()
pattern = re.compile(r'^\w.*', flags=re.MULTILINE)
lines = re.findall(pattern, data)

>>> data   #  note windows line termination
'~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~\r\nsome_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text\r\n   \t\r\n~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~\r\nsome_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text\r\n&&even_more_text_here\r\n\r\n~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~\r\nsome_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text\r\n\r\n~someunicodetext_someunicodetext_someunicodetext~\r\n'

>>> print(lines)
['some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text\r', 'some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text\r', 'some_more_unicode_text_some_more_unicode_text\r']

>>> print(len(lines))
3
```

So the regex matches the "non-marked" non-blank lines as required.

Comment: I tried it, but I believe it also counts blank lines

Comment: If I add `print (match)` under last for loop I do see a lot of whitespace and adding/removing blank lines changes resulting count number. Also forgot to mention, `^\w.*` doesn't produces correct results. It returns only lines that start from normal letters and not some weird symbols (but doesn't returns blank lines)

Comment: about my notepad++ example. in npp `.*` will match any non-blank line. And probably this is why it worked for me. I think this is not true for python.

Comment: Sorry, I have misunderstood your requirement... I thought that you needed to have separate counts for each type of line. My answer is a regex pattern to match those non-blank lines that don't start with ~ or &.

Comment: Yes, I understand. This is the problem. `^[^~&].*$` also matches blank lines. Blank lines don't have `~` or `&`, yet they DO have the beginning `^`, end `$` and stuff in-between `.*`

Comment: Then you simply need to count those lines that are non-blank? [vks's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24879667/21945) will do the trick.

Comment: uhh... do I really explained it this bad? =(
What I'm saying is, your answer doesn't do what you claim it should and I even explained why. I already answered my question myself. Unfortunately I am not able to accept it until 2 days will pass... http://stackoverflow.com/a/24879501/2333940

Comment: I guess you could have explained it better :) My original answer `^\w.*` (with re.MULTILINE) does work for counting "non-marked" lines - which is what you said you had trouble with. BTW, your answer counts blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer. I'm still not sure if I'm handling windows EOL correctly and whatnot, but this seem to be works.
Also I kinda hoped someone will answer with an explanation of where my issue was and why it works the way it works, but oh well.

What this does. We match every line that has ~EOL before it and ends with another EOL. At the same time we make sure we exclude matches that have 2 or more consecutive EOLs.

So. This matches only the lines directly below the lines that are marked with ~

```
import re, codecs

regex = re.compile(r'(?!~(\r\n){2,})~\r\n.*\r\n', re.MULTILINE)
count = 0

with codecs.open('input_file', 'r', 'UTF8') as inputFile:
    inputFile=inputFile.read()
    lines = re.findall(regex, inputFile)
    for match in lines:
        count +=1
print (count)
```

Comment: What is the output of this when you run it? I get "3" - it seems to match the blank lines only. Also, the for loop counter can be replaced with `len(lines)`.

Comment: 3 is the correct answer. Also I explained what it matches. Thanks for the for loop tip. When you look at it visually, you may see garbage, but it does the job.

Comment: 3 whats? You see that your input file contains 3 blank lines AND 3 non-marked lines. Which ones are you actually matching? Try printing `lines` and you'll see [u'', u'', u''] , i.e. 3 blank lines.

Comment: I NEED TO COUNT LINES THAT ARE LOCATED DIRECTLY UNDER THE LINES ENCLOSED IN ~
And this answer does it!
(And solution to count all other lines was already given in the question itself.)

Comment: No need to shout. Where does it say that in your original question? You say, very obtusely, that you need to count the non-marked lines (those that don't start with ~ or &). You do not say that you need to count the lines following a line enclosed by ~ - you say non-marked lines. Anyway, if you think that your answer is correct go and use it. Have fun debugging it later when your input file changes.

Comment: Yes non-marked lines. there are 3 of them. can't you see? Can't you see which ones of them actually unmarked? Exactly the ones under each line in ~

Comment: You are matching the blank lines, not the non-marked lines. There are 3 of both, so the answer is 3 in both cases. But you are fooling yourself, you are not counting non-marked lines, you are counting blank lines. Try changing your input file to have an extra non-marked line.

Comment: "Have fun debugging it later when your input file changes." have nothing to do with the question. I had a problem I need to solve. If the input will change, that will be another problem.

Comment: I do not match blank lines. none of the blank lines has ~EOL before it `~\r\n.*` this means "something that has EOL before it and has a `~` before that EOL. Seriously dude learn to read. None of the blank lines fit this definition, as you should be able to see. In case there are consecutive blank lines, I added lookahead to take care of them.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to argue with you, but I also don't want you to go on believing that your solution is correct when it is not. You should understand that your solution is flawed, and that it will cause problems for you later on. You should check it and correct with the regex pattern that I suggested initially - this will solve the problem.

Comment: I agree that my solution may be really ugly, but it produces correct results. I don't "believe" in anything. I see the numbers and they are exactly what I expect them to be. How many lines are there that are not blank, that don't start with & and don't enclosed in ~ ? There are 3 of them. My code produces exactly this answer. If you don't understand the logic behind it, it doesn't makes it less correct.

Comment: Then `print(3)` would be just as acceptable to you? It produces the expected number so it must be correct.

Comment: No, because I'm going to run this on many similar files. If you don't understand how this answer works, feel free to ask. I believe I explained it multiple times though. In the answer and in comments.

Comment: Then, unless the number of blank lines in each file always equals the number of non-marked lines, you will find that your solution is incorrect.

Comment: How does your answer work. Can you please show the output of `print(lines)` on the line after `re.findall()`?

Comment: If at some point in file the number of blank lines is different, this solution ignores them. It is done in this part `(?!~(\r\n){2,})`. I'll see what I can do about showing the output, but if you expect it to be human-readable, you might be disappointed. To be more specific, if it detects more than one linebreak in a row (and 2 linebreaks in a row required for 1 blank line). So the amount of blank lines is irrelevant.

Comment: `(` is a group, `?!` means do not match, `~(\r\n)` any linebreaks after ~, `{2,}` in case there are 2 or more of them (minimum 2 equals to blank line), `)` closed group And what comes after that is what we Do match: `~`, each ~,`\r\n` followed by linebreak, `.*\r\n` followed by anything until it hits another linebreak.

`print(lines)` returns this `['', '', '']`. Which is fine. I never claimed that it will return the actual text. Why it looks like this - that's for python experts. If it actually matches start of the nonmarked lines, or end, or whatever else related them - I don't care.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57739/discussion-between-user2333940-and-mhawke).

Comment: I've edited my earlier answer to show how a much simpler regex pattern will work properly for any combination of non-marked lines, and any eol convention.  Your regex will not work if you have 2 or more consecutive non-marked lines - it will only count them if they are followed by a blank line. Also, adding blank lines before and after marked lines affects the count. You should use a simpler regex.

Comment: Do you see 2 or more consecutive non-marked lines in the example I provided? I don't. This program is meant to work with very specific type of files. If it will fail due to file being a little different - that is only a good thing.  That would mean that input file have an issue and if I'll feel like it, I might be able to catch this error in my program (but I don't want to)

Comment: Your data sample looks pretty generic, but how would we know? If you don't want to do it the obvious and logical way, that's up to you; I pity whomever has to maintain your code. There is some merit to the failure argument, but I doubt that it will fail in an obvious way - it will probably show up as an odd bug. If the file format is that crucial then you should also be explicitly checking input files for conformation. Good luck with it.... you'll need it.

Comment: "but how would we know?" you don't. I expect you to answer the question I asked, based on the given data. What you're trying to do is to answer it based on some assumptions about possible input data. Just saying, I'm not trying to blame you. This is might be due to the fact that threare too much noobs here. But if anything, it is better to ask the question "can your data be any different from the example you posted?" before proceeding to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

The "non-marked" lines can be identified as the lines which aren't bland *and* do not start with `~` *and* do not start with `&`.

So the following regex would work:

`^[^&\s].*`

read: `^` = match at the beginning, `[^...]` = a single charachter which is not in, `&\s` = the charchter `&` or a whitespace character (i.e. not one of those), `.*` = anything can come after that.

(I put in the `\s` just in case, because you said you're having problems with newlines. I'm not sure it is needed)

Also, it is much better to read the file line by line. You get:

```
import re, codecs
pattern = re.compile(r'^[^&\s].*')
with codecs.open("some_input_file", "r", "UTF8") as inputFile:
    count = sum( 1 for line in inputFile if re.search(pattern, line) )
print (count)
```